# write NULL in JSON object from R

Tags: r, json

I'm writing a JSON object from R where one of the values is `null`. But I cannot figure out how to write it in R so that in JSON appears as: `null` and not `"null"` nor `{}`.

Here is what I have in R:

```
id <- "S_0001"
count <- NULL
o <- list("id"=id, "count"=count)
toJSON(o, pretty=TRUE)
```

But this gives me the following JSON:

```
 {
  "id": ["S_0001"],
  "count": {}
 }
```

And I need to get:

```
 {
   "id": ["S_0001"],
   "count": null
 }
```

I tried `unlist(NULL)`, or `unbox("null")`, etc. but with no luck. 
I've seen several posts on how to retrieve a `null` value from JSON to R, but not the inverse.

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the `null` option:

```
> toJSON(o, null="null", pretty=TRUE)
{
  "id": ["S_0001"],
  "count": null
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed. I also had a dataframe with one column as `null`, so I had to define it as `df$columnX <- list(NULL)` to make it work. I write it here in case is useful for anyone else.

Comment: @LRD There is a solution to your problem! See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a data.frame and stumbled on this post:
Use similar approach as @Stephane, but with `na="null"`. Without it the column would not appear if it previously had `NA` as value:

```
> myDF = data.frame(a = c(1, NA), b = c(NA, 'c'))
> myDF
   a    b
1  1 <NA>
2 NA    c
> toJSON(myDF, na="null", pretty=TRUE)
[
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": null
  },
  {
    "a": null,
    "b": "c"
  }
] 
> toJSON(myDF, pretty=TRUE)
[
  {
    "a": 1
  },
  {
    "b": "c"
  }
]
```